# The method getLayoutInflater(Bundle) in the type Fragment is not applicable for the arguments ()

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout-inflater

I'm trying to use a custom datePicker [date picker](http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-create-custom-date-time-picker.html/)

but I'm getting this error when inflating the root Layout inside a fragment :

```
 public void button_click(View view) {

                // Create the dialog
                final Dialog mDateTimeDialog = new Dialog(view.getContext());
                // Inflate the root layout
        final RelativeLayout mDateTimeDialogView = (RelativeLayout)getLayoutInflater()
                            .inflate(R.layout.datepick,false);
           .....
```

How can I fix this ?

**EDIT**

This code works :

```
// Inflate the root layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) view.getContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    final RelativeLayout mDateTimeDialogView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.datepick, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have any parent view get as a argument of inflate.
eq: view.inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot);

```
view.inflate(int resource, parentView, false);
```

Comment: thanks @Hosein , is there any method to get the parent view ?

Comment: I tried this : 
final RelativeLayout mDateTimeDialogView = view.inflate(R.layout.datepick, view.getParent(), false);
but get this error : 
The method inflate(Context, int, ViewGroup) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (int, ViewParent, boolean)